# Weird bone rotations between keyframes

Tags: animation

This is the first time I post here, and I m having a reoccurring problem with my animations.

Usually this happens on elbows and knees that are IK controlled by the foot, but this time there are more bones affected and not only the ones controlled by IK. It’s the pelvis bone and many more.
Specifics about this situation is that I had an animation retargeted from another skeleton to my armature. While most of the animation plays nice there is this point between frames that behave inappropriately.
Also another thing to note is that I usually use quaternions for
rotation, the retargeting uses Euler.

As the title says, I have included a link with a video showing the problem. I know about quaternions/Euler axis and gimble lock, which I figure that this is what's happening (might be wrong idk).

My question is how do I go about fixing it?

Video link : https://i.imgur.com/9NZthyG

Things that failed so far :

Isolating the frames and tweaking inbetween

Deleting the keyframes altogether

Comment: have you tried to fix it with the pole target bones? with IK locks in the Bone panel? change the IK Solver? Maybe share your armature with its animation? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I definately will give pole target bones and IK locks or even the IK Solver a more indepth look. Also the link seems so usefull.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: You are right ofc. It’s just that I lack the words to even begin to describe more thoroughly the problem. I ll try and be more descriptive.

Comment: Ended up having the animation retargeted and used 1 frame intervals to completely eliminate the space in between key frames. I hope I can figure out a better/easier solution.

Comment: here with the same issue. "...Ended up having the animation retargeted and used 1 frame intervals to completely eliminate the space in between key frames. "
seems like my option as well..